# RMD to DOCx , Can't render {=openxml} chunks inside table cells like huxtable and other?

Tags: r, markdown, knitr, openxml, huxtable

HOW get rendered openxml chunks inside cells of tables in RMD to DOCx ?
I just get same openxml text (mdt) inside tables instead of content ..

any suggestions please?

xml_test.RMD:

Updated Test  RMD code :

````
    ---
output:
  word_document:
    reference_docx: ./template.docx
    keep_md: yes
    md_extensions: +raw_tex
editor_options:
  chunk_output_type: console
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```

```{r, setuplib, include=FALSE}
#library(tidyverse)
library(knitr)
#library(rmarkdown)
#library(dplyr)
#library(stringr)
library(huxtable)
library(kableExtra)
#library(ftExtra)

```


```{r, xml-test, echo=FALSE, collapse = FALSE}

# XML CONTENT
text_xml <- "<w:p><w:r><w:t>Example text.</w:t></w:r></w:p>"

sanitize(text_xml, type = "rtf")

knitr::asis_output(" \n")

sanitize(text_xml, type = "html")

knitr::asis_output(" \n")

#sanitize(text_xml, type = "latex")

#knitr::asis_output(" \n")

#to_ht <- c(knitr::asis_output(mdt), knitr::asis_output(mdt))
to_ht <- c(text_xml)

#ht <- huxtable::as_hux(to_ht, add_colnames = TRUE, add_rownames = TRUE, escape_contents=FALSE, autoformat = FALSE)
ht <- huxtable::as_hux(text_xml, add_colnames = FALSE, add_rownames = FALSE, escape_contents=FALSE, autoformat = FALSE)

#markdown(ht) <- TRUE
#ht <- set_markdown(ht)

# BAD XML OUTPUT INSIDE CELLS
theme_grey(ht)
knitr::asis_output(" \n")


#knitr::asis_output(ht)
knitr::asis_output(" \n")

# NORMAL XML OUTPUT  HERE:
knitr::asis_output(as.character(text_xml))


```
````

I found **as_hux()** has incorrect *sanitize* text in:  " *<w:p><w:r><w:t>Example text.</w:t></w:r></w:p>*
"
instead of RAW or WORD in md:
"*<w:p><w:r><w:t>Example text.</w:t></w:r></w:p>*"

as result I have this issue with  wrong output in WORD huxtable cell

**QUESTION: how i can avoid this conversion in MD file ?**

Comment: Updated Test  RMD code :

Comment: this is  part of results in MD file:    ..........     ```{=openxml}  .................<w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:eastAsia="Arial" w:cs="Arial"/><w:sz w:val="22"/><w:szCs w:val="22"/><w:color w:val="111111"/></w:rPr><w:t xml:space="preserve">&lt;w:p&gt;&lt;w:r&gt;&lt;w:t&gt;Example text.&lt;/w:t&gt;&lt;/w:r&gt;&lt;/w:p&gt;</w:t></w:r></w:p></w:tc></w:tr></w:tbl>```

 
 
<w:p><w:r><w:t>Example text.</w:t></w:r></w:p>

Comment: Which library are you using for conversion?

Comment: It is just normal PANDOC output

Comment: Have you tried using `escape_contents()`? It might work though I've never tried what you are trying to do.

Comment: Yes sure ,    escape_contents()   not work in this case too ((

Comment: You might look into flextable and see if it has facilities for doing this. huxtable is using flextable/officer under the hood to print to Word.

Comment: for flex table same result (